# Split string words in pairs for all side by side words

Tags: python

I need split strings into words, then join each consecutive word in pairs, like so:

```
"This is my subject string"
```

Would go to:

```
"This is"    
"is my"  
"my subject"  
"subject string"
```

The strings would be anywhere from 5 words to 250 words. Also, it would be doing this on a lot of data, 1GB or so. Is there an efficient way to do this in Python?

I've seen lots advice about which methods for things are most efficient, so wanted to ask first.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What are you constraints (memory, time, etc) for processing 1GB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Pythonic way

```
from itertools import izip
[' '.join(pair) for pair in izip(words[:-1], words[1:])]
```

*izip* will keep it more or less efficient

Comment: @Alok - for sentences of up 250 words, this is not much of overhead

Comment: @volcano see my solution for the most efficient, maybe not fasest in raw speed, but it won't create two copy lists

Comment: @jamylak - very nice indeed, something to learn from. I had problem with solutions that iterate over (ugh) indices

Comment: @jamylak - Just had similar problem at work, so came up with this izip(iter(words[:-1]), iter(words[1:]). What do you say of this?

Comment: This and the other similar method were the fastest in my testing. From what I read iterators are supposed to be very fast but I've been using Python for a few weeks only. Not sure why the thread was closed, bit maybe it will help other novices. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @volcano that's the exact same thing as you have now, you are still taking slices `[::]` which make a shallow copy. **note** the first slice `[:-1]` is redundant

Answer (score 6):

You could do it with the split method and list comprehensions:

```
text = "This is my subject string"
words = text.split() #note that split without arguments splits on whitespace
pairs = [words[i]+' '+words[i+1] for i in range(len(words)-1)]
print(pairs)
```

Comment: How does split fair with big data? It doesn't return generator afaik.

Comment: It doesn't, but 250 words in a string should not be a problem. The bottleneck is the list comprehension, but it can be rationalized depending on the demands.

Comment: Right, I misread the question, I thought his strings would be 1GB or so.

Comment: @gatto Making this into a generator involves substituting the `[]` for `()` in the list comp. Or are you talking about the process of splitting into words?

Comment: I was talking about `str.split`.

Answer (score 5):

There's an [`itertools` recipe called pairwise](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) built exactly for this! You'd be crazy not to use it too.

```
>>> from itertools import tee, izip
>>> def pairwise(iterable):
        "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
        a, b = tee(iterable)
        next(b, None)
        return izip(a, b)


>>> list(pairwise(text.split()))
[('This', 'is'), ('is', 'my'), ('my', 'subject'), ('subject', 'string')]
```

Comment: could you explain the first line `"s -> (s0, s1), ...`

Comment: @masfenix That's just the docstring, it's a visual representation of the result eg. (elem0, elem1), (elem1, elem2), etc.

Comment: Okay thanks, could you go line by line through your function. I am learning python and am confused.

Comment: @masfenix `tee` makes a copy of an iterator, `next(b, None)` advances the `b` forward by one item. Then you `izip` the two iterators together, so each pair will have an element from `a` and `b` but `b`'s element will be one ahead of the one from a

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "This is my subject string"
>>> re.findall(r'(\w+)\s+(?=(\w+))', text)
[('This', 'is'), ('is', 'my'), ('my', 'subject'), ('subject', 'string')]
```

If you need a generator out of this, just use `re.finditer`

```
pairs = (m.groups() for m in re.finditer(r'(\w+)\s+(?=(\w+))', text))
```

This is very fast/efficient, the second version will be the most efficient since it doesn't store all the words in memory at once, however it won't be as fast. You'll have to profile the methods suggested to you to see which one works for you.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the naive implementation should work just fine, assuming each *string* is smallish (not 1GB)

```
string = "This is my subject string"

words = string.split()
prevWord = None

for word in words:
    if prevWord != None:
        print prevWord, word
    prevWord = word
```

As usual when dealing with a reasonably large dataset you'll want to read one item, process it, read the next item, etc.  Don't try to `split()` the entire file.

Comment: This is pretty much what I had in mind but being very new to Python I didn't know if there was a better way. The strings themselves would be smallish.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind calculating the length of the initial list, then you can do something like this:

```
s = 'this is a test string'.split()
n = len(s)
for first, second in itertools.izip(itertools.islice(s, 0, n-1), itertools.islice(s, 1, n)):
    print(first, second)
```

This outputs:

```
('this', 'is')
('is', 'a')
('a', 'test')
('test', 'string')
```

This should be efficient for large amount of data since you are not creating a huge list (other than what you already have).