# python - Split a string in to two character array

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
str = "abc defg hijk lmn lmno oepq"
```

how to get output like this

```
array = ['abc degf', 'degf hijk' , 'hijk lmn' ,'lmn lmno', 'lmno opeq' ]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Also, don't use `str` as a variable name, as that is overwriting the built-in function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126122/split-string-words-in-pairs-for-all-side-by-side-words/16126151

Answer (score -1):

Here is one way to do this.  We can duplicate the second through second-to-last string values in the input, then use `re.findall` to simply take all pairs of words.

```py
inp = "abc defg hijk lmn lmno oepq"
inp = re.sub(r'(?<= )(\w+)(?= )', r'\1 \1', inp)
output = re.findall(r'\w+ \w+', inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
['abc defg', 'defg hijk', 'hijk lmn', 'lmn lmno', 'lmno oepq']
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
l = [f'{s[x]} {s[x+1]}' for x,_ in  enumerate(s) if x < len(s) - 1]
print(l)
```

output:

```
['abc defg', 'defg hijk', 'hijk lmn', 'lmn lmno', 'lmno oepq']
```